# How to make sure test always runs in the same time zone

Tags: java, unit-testing, timezone, datetime-format, epoch

I have a function that parses an Unix epoch time into the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` like this in order to export it to a file:

```
    public static final SimpleDateFormat REQIF_DATE_FORMAT_WITH_MILLIS
        = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

    public static String convertEpochStringToReqifDateString(String epochString) {
        Date timestamp = new Date(Long.parseLong(epochString));
        return REQIF_DATE_FORMAT_WITH_MILLIS.format(timestamp);
    }
```

Now, I have tests for this export, but while they pass locally, they fail on the server because it's apparently in a different time zone. Specifically, the differences look like this:

```
LAST-CHANGE="2017-03-13T21:36:44.261+01:00"
LAST-CHANGE="2017-03-13T20:36:44.261Z"
```

I have already tried running a number of things before the test in order to make sure that the test is always run in the same time zone, such as:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
```

As well as the JUnitPioneer annotation:

```
@DefaultTimeZone("UTC")
```

...however, none of them seemed to affect the parsing output at all.

What can I do about this? All I want is some way to ensure that my tests are run in the same time zone regardless of where the machine they are run is standing so I can test the export correctly.

Comment: Is there a good reason to be using `Date`, as opposed to `java.time.Instant` (which has its own `toString()` method, and _always_ prints in Zulu?

Comment: (BTW, I hope you're just omitting the code to ensure that only one thread accesses the SimpleDateFormat at a time? If not, you need to ensure that, e.g. using a `ThreadLocal` instead. You wouldn't need to do this with an `Instant`)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Don’t ensure that the tests are run in a specific time zone. Write both your code and your tests so they are independent of the JVM’s default time zone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

You can use [`Instant.ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-) to convert the epoch milliseconds into `Instant` and then use the `Instant#toString`. However, [`Instant#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) omits the fraction-of-second part if they are zero. Therefore, if you need the value strictly in the pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`, you can convert the `Instant` to `OffsetDateTime` and format it using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // An example epoch milliseconds
        long millis = 1631113620000L;

        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
        String strDateTime = instant.toString();
        System.out.println(strDateTime);

        // If you need the value strictly in the pattern, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        strDateTime = odt.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(strDateTime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-09-08T15:07:00Z
2021-09-08T15:07:00.000Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/sxyCHU)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this would be to use `java.time.Instant`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(epochString));
return instant.toString();
```

This will always print in UTC, whatever the JVM's default time zone.

---

You can also do this by [setting the time zone on the `SimpleDateFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)):

```
REQIF_DATE_FORMAT_WITH_MILLIS.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Note that you need to take care with a shared `SimpleDateFormat` because it has mutable state, which is corrupted by access from multiple threads. You can have a separate instance per thread like so:

```
static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> REQIF_DATE_FORMAT_WITH_MILLIS =
    ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
      sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      return sdf;
    });
```

and then access it with:

```
return REQIF_DATE_FORMAT_WITH_MILLIS.get().format(timestamp);
```

But this is getting quite messy, isn't it? Much easier just to use `Instant`.